# Player Keeps Sticking On The Platform Collision Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get a good collision with my rectangles but I feel like my method is bad because when ever I job and collide  with my other platform my player keeps getting stuck on it, ***is there  a way I could make it collide good without it getting stuck*** I am just looking for a good collision Thank You!

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/56f65b6338fca912e4bfffbe16a62287) < as you can see my player keeps getting stuck on the platform its the same thing for left and right when I collide with the platform it will just make my player stuck without proper collision

```
        # collisions
        for platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                if (platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.right, playerman.rect.bottom) or
                    platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.left, playerman.rect.bottom)):
                    playerman.y = platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                    playerman.moveright = True
                    playerman.moveleft = True
                
                if (platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.right, playerman.rect.top) or
                    platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.right, playerman.rect.bottom - 10)):
                    playerman.moveright = False
                elif (platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.left, playerman.rect.top) or
                      platform.rect.collidepoint(playerman.rect.left, playerman.rect.bottom - 10)):
                    playerman.moveleft = False
            else:
                playerman.moveright = True
                playerman.moveleft = True
```

my full code:  [script](https://pastebin.com/DsB77TGY)

I been searching everywhere for proper collision and I cant manage to find any good working ones

Comment: Maybe you can check for collision when you are changing the `playerman` `x,y`.  This makes it possible to move to the side of objects, because you currently know how much the *desired* movement is, and can then adjust.  For example, say you want to move `x + 10`, but can only move `3` pixels because of collision.  It's easier to work this out when you know what's going on (trying to move right 10, collision after 3).  But in your current code, the movement has already happened, and your collision code is trying to "fix it up" afterwards, and determine if valid.. but you don't know the *from*.

Answer (score 1):

From your video it looks like the collision detection does not work if you come up from below a block.

In general (see below for an example): I encountered the same "puzzle" with my game and as far as I could see there are two possible ways.

1. **Pre-Checking**

You check how far away the player is from the closest "block" and let the player move only so far. This includes:

- checking which blocks are the closest to the player
- checking the distance to each close block and calculating the remaining possible x pixels  the player can move in direction z.
- move player exactly x pixels in direction z.

2. **Post-Checking** (I used this as it was easier to figure out on my own back then)

You move the player according to his current speed and then check for collisions. If you get a collision, you move the player *back* for the amount of pixels which is the intersection between player-border and block-border.

- move player according to his speed to the full extent
- check collisions for all close blocks (or all blocks on the map for starters and you can improve the performance from there)
- if you get a collision, calculate by how much the player intersects with the colliding block. This is easy if your player's hitbox is a rectangle and you work with a tilemap made up of rectangular blocks, you can simply subtract player.x  and block.x coordinates
- move the player back (before updating the screen) by that amount of pixels.

If you want to learn more about it and have in-depth code examples (if you don't want to try and error by yourself until you figure it out) I suggest searching on youtube for pygame-2D collision detections, there are great teachers on there.

Here is an excerpt of my collisiondetection_x_axis() method (self references the player!)

```
# move player etc ...
for tile in map_tiles: # for all tiles on the map
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.hitboxBody, tile):
        if self.SpeedX < 0 and tile.rect.right > self.hitboxBody.rect.left:  # moving left and collision
             # move char back to "in front of the wall"
             self.rect.x += tile.rect.right - self.hitboxBody.rect.left
             self.SpeedX = 0  # set speedX to zero, as we cannot move in that direction anymore

        elif self.SpeedX > 0 and self.hitboxBody.rect.right > tile.rect.left:  # moving right and collision
             # move char back to "in front of the wall"
             self.rect.x -= self.hitboxBody.rect.right - tile.rect.left
             self.SpeedX = 0  # set speedX to zero, as we cannot move in that direction anymore
```

collision_detection_y_axis:

```
for tile in map_tiles: # for all tiles on the map
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.hitboxBody, tile):
        if self.SpeedY < 0 and tile.rect.bottom > self.hitboxBody.rect.top:  # moving up
            self.rect.y += tile.rect.bottom - self.hitboxBody.rect.top # move char back to "below the wall"
            self.SpeedY = 0
        elif self.SpeedY > 0 and self.hitboxBody.rect.bottom > tile.rect.top:  # moving downwards
            self.rect.y -= self.hitboxBody.rect.bottom - tile.rect.top # move back to "on top of the wall"
            self.SpeedY = 0
            self.jumping = False  # on ground
```

Edit: this requires your movement between collision-checks to be less than the width of a block, otherwise your character can 'glitch' through blocks if he has enough speed.

Note: you should take into the account the direction your player is moving **before** you do collision-tests, it makes it easier to determine which side of the player will possibly collide first with a block. For instance if you are moving to the right, then the right side of the player will collide with the left side of a block. Then write a collision detection for those two points as well as consequent action (e.g. reset to a position in front of the block and `speed_x = 0`)

PS: Try and use the function [pygame.Rect.colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect), it tests if two rects overlap (=collision), I have a feeling the way you set up your collidepoint-functions don't return collisions for all possible scenarios.

Comment: I tried your method but I am still having the same problem [video](https://gyazo.com/a775a1ea31a957896432b4cb0fa7610b)  [script](https://pastebin.com/cAndisTY) I might need a little more help with this problem I dont know why its hard for me to just make collisions between platforms

Comment: After looking at your code again - you check whether the *corner points* of your character collide with the rect - if your character is "inside" the block, the top corners are on top of the block-rect, the bottom corners are below the block-rect. Hence there is no collision. Furthermore, you restrict movement left-right once a collision happens, but NOT movement up/down (!) (` playerman.moveright = False`). I think you should try setting up the collision detection and resulting actions from scratch. I will append my collisiondetection for the y-axis in a minute as well.

Comment: I forgot the collision-detection line (added it now into the examples). If you still can't find your bug, I suggest taking a pen and paper, draw how your player is moving, where the block is, how they collide and which points you need to test for a collision. You can also use `collide_rect` to determine if two rects overlap (then you don't need to test for a specific point as you do up to now) and then handle the collision based on the direction the player is moving.

Comment: @HabibIsmail, I just realized that you have only one variable for speed in your new script? **You handle collisions only when you move left-right, not when you move up-down!** how do you differentiate between speed along the x and the y axis? I think you need to implement a collision detection while you jump (move upwards) as well..